# Cannot convert type table-type to 'string'

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote this code below in WPF, But it says that :

> Error 1   Cannot convert type 'WpfApplication.Role' to 'string'.

Here in Code:

1. Roles and N_Roles_Users are names of Database table.
2. currentUser is string parameter.
3. myEntities is name of database.

   ```
       public List<Role> GetUserRoles( string currentUser)
       {
           nrcsaEntities dbcon = new nrcsaEntities();
           N_Roles_Users allroles = null;
           List<Role> roleslist = new List<Role>();
           if (allroles == null)
           {
           allroles = new N_Roles_Users();
               {
               var y = from x in dbcon.N_Roles_Users where x.user_name == currentUser select x.role_name;
               foreach (var a in y)
                   {
                   roleslist.Add(a);  //Here it is Generating Error

                   }
               q.ItemsSource = roleslist.ToList();

               }
           }
       return roleslist;
       }
   ```

Comment: You are putting `x.role_name` (which is presumably a string) into a `List<Role>`. Why do you expect this to work?

Comment: what properties does 'a' have ?

Comment: @DanielKelley i want to save all role names of currentUser in roleslist.

Comment: @bhs a has string datatype.

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh Then make your list a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 3):

You query returns `x.role_name`, which seems to be a `string`:

```
var y = from x in dbcon.N_Roles_Users
        where x.user_name == currentUser
        select x.role_name;
```

That's why you can't assign it to `List<Role>`. Change your query to select `Role` entity instead of just role name and it should work.

Or change your method declaration to return `List<string>`:

```
public List<string> GetUserRoles( string currentUser)
```

And change `roleslist` to be `List<string>` too:

```
List<string> roleslist = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<Role> rolesList` is a list of type `Role`.

Your query appears to return a collection of strings.

Below, you attempt to add a `string` to the list where it should be a `Role`

```
roleslist.Add(a);
```

By the looks of things you actually want to add the `Role` object itself, in which case you can update your query to return a collection of roles:

```
var y = from x in dbcon.N_Roles_Users where x.user_name == currentUser select x;
```